# UITableViewを上部まで埋めないと、UISwitchが正しく表示されない

Tags: swift

以下のコード(**TestViewController.swift**)で、UITableViewCellにUISwitchを埋め込みました。

**TestViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

class TestViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    var sections = ["section1","section2","section2.5","section3"]
    var values = [["value1-1","value1-2","value1-3"],["value2-1","value2-2","value2-3"],["value2.5-1","value2.5-2","value2.5-3"],["value3-1","value3-2","value3-3","value3-4","value3-5","value3-6","value3-7"]]
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    @objc func switchChanged(_ sender : UISwitch!)
    {
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        return values[section].count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testTableViewCells", for: indexPath)
        
        if values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == "value1-1"
        {
            print("1-1")
             let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
             switchView.setOn(true, animated: true)
             switchView.tag = 0
             switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
             cell.accessoryView = switchView
        }
        else
        {
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.disclosureIndicator
        }
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell;
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let label : UILabel = UILabel()
        
        label.text = sections[section]
        label.alpha = 0.5
        
        return label
    }
    
    //高さを指定
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 40
    }

    //cellがタップされた時の処理
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
    {
        print(values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row])
    }
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        
        return sections.count
    }
    
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }
}
```

このコードでは、value1-1のCellのみでUISwitchを表示するコードになっているのですが、TableViewを下にスクロールしていくと、value3-6や、value3-7のCellなど、意図しない位置にもUISwitchが表示されてしまいます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

UITableView,UITableViewCellはStoryboard上で配置しており、以下のような構造になっています。
UIViewにぴったりくっつけず、上部に余白を残してUITableViewを配置しています。
(UITableViewの上に、UINavigationBarを配置する都合などでこのようにしています。)

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

上部に余白を残さずにUITableViewを配置した場合、同様の問題は起きないので、余白がこの問題を引き起こしていると考えています。この問題を解決する方法はありますか？

Comment: 私が立てた仮説を検証するために、質問者さんに試してもらいたいことがあります。現在テーブルの総行数は17ですが、これを一気に100行程度に増やしてみてください。私の仮説が正しければ、UITableViewの余白の有無に関係なく、そして天地のサイズがいくつであっても、「意図しない位置にもUISwitchが表示されてしま」う現象が起きるはずです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。試してみましたが、たしかに100個程度まで増やしてみると同様の問題が発生するようでした。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 上部に余白を残さずにUITableViewを配置した場合、同様の問題は起きないので、余白がこの問題を引き起こしていると考えています。

問題が起きやすくなる条件は見つけられたようですが、それがこの問題の直接の原因とは限りません。

`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`を以下のように書き換えて、同じ問題が発生するかどうか確かめてみてください。

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testTableViewCells", for: indexPath)
        
        if values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == "value1-1" {
            print("1-1")
            let switchView = UISwitch(frame: .zero)
            switchView.isOn = true
            switchView.tag = 0
            switchView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.switchChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
            cell.accessoryView = switchView
            cell.accessoryType = .none //<-
        } else {
            cell.accessoryView = nil //<-
            cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
        }
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

(細かいところで趣味に合わない書き方を修正してありますが、`<-`を付けたところ以外は本質的なものではありません。)

根本的な問題点は、あなたの`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`がセルの再利用を考慮した実装になっていないことにあります。

一度`UISwitch`を置いたセルがスクロール等によって、再利用された場合に、あなたの`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`はその`UISwitch`を消すようなことはしていませんから、予測不可能なある状況の場合には、それがそのまま表示されることになります。

「余白」はセルの再利用が発生しやすくなる条件であり、根本的な原因ではありません。

---

iOSにおいて、viewの生成は比較的重い処理なので、`tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`の中で毎回動的にview(今の場合は`UISwitch`)を生成すると言うプログラミングは推奨されません。

見かけの違う2種類のセルを使うなら、Reuse Identifierを変えて管理することにより、再利用による問題も発生しにくくなり、応答性も良くなります。

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        let cell: UITableViewCell
        if values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == "value1-1" {
            print("1-1")
            //`"value1-1"`の場合は、異なるReuse Identifierを使用する
            //storyboardでこのIdentifier用のセルを別に準備しておく
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "switchTableViewCells", for: indexPath)
            //...
        } else {
            cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "testTableViewCells", for: indexPath)
            //...
        }
        
        cell.textLabel!.text = values[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！この方法に書き換えたところ、Cellを100個程度まで増やした場合でもUISwitchが問題なく表示されるようになりました！